# Como modificar a URL de www.meusite.com/index.php?secao=quemsomos para www.meusite.com/quemsomos?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Meu arquivo .htaccess está dessa maneira:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?secao=$1
```

Quero traduzir a url www.meusite.com/index.php?secao=quemsomos
para www.meusite.com/quemsomos

Está correto da maneira que coloquei? Pq não está dando certo.

Comment: qual o erro? veja esse link http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis.

Answer (score 0):

A regra funciona corretamente, mas estas duas condições:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

significam que o arquivo (`-f`) não existe e que a pasta (`-d`) não existe, e deve ser cumprido para executar a reescrita.

Provavelmente, você tem uma pasta chamada `/quemsomos`, então a reescrita não se aplica.

Remova ou renomeie essa pasta ou remova essa condição.